# Custom Bootstrap/jetstrap navbar color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jetstrap

so I created and downloaded a theme in jetstrap. Now all I need to do is create the is set up my custom colors. I am just using the bootstrap.css that I got when I downloaded the jetstrap theme. Does anyone know where I change the colors?

Answer (score 3):

you need to change the CSS for the `.navbar-inner` class. By default Bootstrap uses `background-image` for a subtle gradient, so you'll want to try something like this:

```
.navbar-inner {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #111;
}
```

Where `#111` is the color you want. If you want to change it to a different gradient, try a CSS3 gradient generator tool and paste that in instead.